# Insert an array of object from an array of object into mysql database php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm new to JSON and I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcEZu.png) JSON data that I already JSON.stringify for me to pass into my back-end(php) using AJAX. At the PHP side, I want to store the following (bizName, bizAddress, salesman, term, duedate, and area) into a table named "orderDetail " and the data inside ordersArr into another table named "orders" and use the Primary Key ID from orderDetail table as a foreign key for each orders in the "orders".

I've researched many methods for me to use, what should I use in this scenario?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use [json\_​decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to ... decode JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON format has a error, in the first line you have to use `"order" :` instead of `order` and make the whole data a object by adding curly bracket in start and end. Like :

```
{
  "order" : [{
      "bizName": "Sample Business",
      "bizAddress": "Sample Address",
      "salesman": "store",
      "term": "COD",
      "dueDate": "2822-18-11",
      "area": "Sample Area",
      "ordersArr":[{
        "itemID": 2,
        "name": "Sample Item",
        "qty": 1,
        "price":25,
        "uom": "BOX"
        "amount": 25
        }]
    }]
}
```

To convert JSON to a php array use `$php_array = json_decode($json,TRUE);`
Rest of the code below

```
foreach($php_array['order'] as $order){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO orderDetail 
  VALUES (NULL,{$order['bizName']})"; // add more values as the bizName ,if this not works first save the biz Name in another variable and then pass it in the query
  mysqli_query($conn,$sql); // $conn is your connection, running the query
  $order_id = mysqli_insert_id(); // returns last insert id
  foreach($order['ordersArr'] as $ordersArr){
    $sql = "" // write the insert SQL for table orders and run it
    //use $order_id as primary key id   from orderDetail table
  }
}
```

Comment: should i still use the mysqli_insert_id() if I set the primary id from orderDetail table into a foreign key in the orders table? cause I think it is unecessary

Comment: You can also use a mysqli query to find the last inserted id